# How to take control of the primary OS thread in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to embed a ruby1.9 interpreter in a program. I am currently using `forkOS` in my `hruby` package, but it seems this only works for ruby 1.8 and 2.x. It looks like 1.9 needs to execute in the primary thread. As a side node, there is *no* documentation one how to do such a thing, so the only pointer to my current problem is [here](https://github.com/DFHack/dfhack/issues/271#issuecomment-55113005).

Is there a way to take control of the primary thread to run all my FFI calls ?

Comment: Maybe an option could be using an hack similar to [`postGUISync`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.13.4/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-General-General.html#v:postGUISync) of the `gtk` package. (Not sure if this is really relevant, but...)

Comment: If I understand this properly, this is like [my makeSafe call](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hruby-0.2.7/docs/Foreign-Ruby-Safe.html#v:makeSafe). This is necessary because the ruby interpreter expects all calls to be made from the same thread, yet you might want several threads to have access to the ruby functions. However in the case of GTK they seem to also have a binding to run things in the main loop (that isn't necessarily the primary thread) ...

Comment: I think if you start up Haskell from the main thread and then call into Haskell via the (ffi)[https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html#using-own-main] the Haskell thread is then bound to the main thread and all FFI calls from that thread will appear to come from the main C thread.

Comment: You mean writing a C program an running the Haskell runtime from it ?

Comment: It wouldn't be elegant and I'm not necessarily sure it would work but the documentation seems to suggest that would work. Looking further at the documentation it seems that main is itself a bound thread so it looks likely that it is the primary os thread.

Answer (score 1):

Having done some testing and reading of documentation I have come to the following conclusions. The report says all of this is implementation defined so there is no standard way. The module `Control.Concurrent` states in its documentation that main is a bound thread however it doesn't require that it is the same as the primary OS thread.

Experimentally (at least on Linux 64-bit with GHC 7.8 and 7.10-rc3) the main thread is the OS thread. Given that the main thread is bound it seems there would be no reason for this to be different on other GHC platforms however I cannot test other platforms.

In terms of actually implementing this if you want to program as if ruby was in a different thread you can run most non-ruby stuff in a different thread and communicate with main thread (which talks to the ruby interpreter) via either `MVar`s or `TVar`s. See the comment by @chi for an example of how this is done in `gtk`.

In terms of a library interface you can have a initialisation function that takes a continuation. Your library hijacks the thread at initialisation and then calls the continuation on another thread. Of course you then need to document to users that it must be called in the main thread.

Comment: Looks like it works. Except it fails with my use case, as the ruby interpreter doesn't seem to play nice with the Haskell runtime :(